# Select a certain item unless is null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, iif

I'm trying to pull a certain item unless the first item is null.

```
SELECT  
   FM.FileNumber
   ,FM.ClientsFileNumber AS 'Clients File Number'
   ,FM.FileID AS FileID
   ,S.Name AS Status
   ,FA.ReceivedDate AS 'Contract Fr Seller' --550, 238
   ,FA1.ReceivedDate AS 'Deed To Seller'    --266, 561
   ,FA2.ReceivedDate AS 'Deed Fr Seller'    --40, 629
   ,FA3.ReceivedDate AS 'HUDTo Seller'                     --269, 587
   ,FA4.ReceivedDate AS 'HUDFr Seller'                      --274, 637
   ,FA5.ReceivedDate AS 'Sent HUD to Buyer'          --268
   ,FA6.ReceivedDate AS 'Receive Buyer Signed Docs'          --273
   ,FA7.ReceivedDate AS 'Receive Buyer Funds'                      --119
   ,FA8.ReceivedDate AS 'Closing Completed'                          --272
   ,FA9.ReceivedDate AS 'FC Deed' --344
   -- ,n.Body as Notes
FROM   
   FileMain FM
LEFT OUTER JOIN      
   FileActions FA ON FA.FileID = FM.FileID AND FA.ActionDefID IN (238,550)
                     AND FA.Live = 1 AND FA.ReceiveCoordinatorTypeID = 2
                    --AND FA.ReceivedDate > '2013-03-01'
                    AND FA.ReceivedDate IS NOT NULL
                    AND FA.ActionDefID IS NOT NULL
```

Basically I am trying to get it to select `FA.ActioNDefID = 230` unless that is `NULL`, then I want it to pull `FA.ActionDefID = 550`, and the same for the other multiple selections.

Below is what I am currently getting, now the later one will ALWAYS be 238 unless it is null, basically I am only wanting to get 1 of those File Numbers, if 238 is null, then pull 550 only.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your table structure, some sample data, and what you're trying to achieve? I couldn't really understand from the question here.

Comment: I cannot provide table structure unfortunately, but I modified the post with data.

Comment: @CJBoat, What do you mean by " if 238 is null", do you mean no records find for 238 or some column values for 238 is NULL?

Comment: If ActionDefID =238 is null then pull ActionDefID = 550, so if there is nothing listed for 238, then try to run 550.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest rewrite you query like this, should be more readable

```
SELECT
   ...
  , [Contract Fr Seller] = (SELECT TOP 1 FA.ReceivedDate 
                     FROM FileActions FA 
                     WHERE FA.FileID = FM.FileID
                          AND  FA.ActionDefID IN (238,550)
                          AND FA.Live = 1
                          AND FA.ReceiveCoordinatorTypeID = 2 
                     ORDER BY FA.ActionDefID  -- This will make sure 238 on the top if exist
                      )                                 
FROM FileMain FM
...
```

Comment: I think you just saved my job, thank you so much, that worked! I did have to order by DESC to get the latest instance, but I did not explain that.  Thank you so much!